# importing ShowcaseView with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-library, showcaseview

I'm trying to use the ShowcaseView project in my app but can't get the project to build.

when I run 'gradle clean installDebug' I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hows-it-going'.
```

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':ShowcaseView'] on root project 'hows-it-going'.

I'm using gradle 1.11 and Android Studio 0.54.

I've downloaded the source, and imported the project using file -> Import module -> ShowcaseView
which makes my project structure like:

-project
--app
--ShowcaseView

my settings.gradle file looks like:

```
include ':app', 'ShowcaseView'
```

and in my project level build.gradle I have the following:

```
dependencies {
  compile project (':ShowcaseView')
}
```

Any help with how to include this properly would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently just added `ShowcaseView` to an `Android Studio` project, and I hope this can push you in the correct direction.

My file structure looks something like this:

- project

  - app

    - build.gradle
  - libraries

    - showcase
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle

---

1. Add the files from the [library
   folder](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/tree/master/library)
   of `ShowcaseView` to the showcase directory in the libraries
   directory.
2. Add the showcase directory as a module to your project.
3. Change your app's `build.gradle` file to include:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile project(':libraries:showcase')
   }
   ```
4. Change your `settings.gradle` to include:

   `include ':libraries:showcase'`
5. Sync Project with gradle files

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/1858217) goes over how to do this is much more detail if you have any troubles, but this method works for any library.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of ShowcaseView is available as a .AAR dependency. To use it, add:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}
```

To your build.gradle file and, under the dependencies block, add:

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

I'll get a stable, non-snapshot, version out soon.

Comment: This answer is better than mine, would use the new .AAR dependency over importing the files manually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for maven repo but it seems it doesn't work for me. Maybe different Gradle version? I'm using the latest one - 0.11 and it gives me error: Artifact 'com....library.jar' not found. The repositories block is in the same file as compile command - in app/build.gradle

Answer (score 5):

It should actually be

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
```

That way Maven will use .AAR file

Answer (score 0):

The compile dependency on `ShowcaseView` should likely be defined in `app/build.gradle`, not in the root project's `build.gradle`. Unless a project explicitly (`configurations` block) or implicitly (by applying a plugin such as `java`) defines a `compile` configuration, it won't have one, and an attempt to add a `compile` dependency will result in the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I added this in build.gradle and it worked

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
```