# Android : importing ShowcaseView with gradle but can't import its library as module

Tags: showcaseview

Hello my teacher and masters, I appreciate your time for reading this known issue, I really do.

I respect *Google* by *Android* and everthing. This gradle thing, instead, all of problem coming back to gradle. Anyway, since we are not allowed to ask in other question and since I did a lot of search in this 3 days with no success for now by Showcase View. Here is my problem:

First I found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258446/importing-showcaseview-with-gradle?answertab=oldest#tab-top) solution (answer by AndyGable), and tried to follow his tutorial, but here is my problem:

First question is, what exact folder of Showcase library (I want the name) should I put in which folder of project? I assume that the destination folder is `app\lib` of my project. Here are the pictures.

[image]

Second question:

How can I add showcase library to my project? Unfortunately, all tutorial was not brief and explained for amateurs, even one above. I want to know the steps like you give it to dummy for android studio 0.8.xx.

[image]

full version picture for detail (just in case) [here](http://www.8pic.ir/images/9zi1jgfwcb0iq0xovyme.png)

I tried these steps:

Open project structure > hit dependency > hit + .. and here is stuck. In the above picture I show how my project, setting.gradle, and other things are.

And one other thing:

I decided to avoid "2 - Add the showcase directory as a module to your project." step and followed others :

"3 Change your app's build.gradle file to include:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':libraries:showcase')
}
```

and so on and now I have showcase library included in my dependency but getting the error shown in the picture above: `configuration with name 'default' not found`!!!

I am really tired and this transparent activity is inevitable for me. Appreciate all of you as my brothers teachers and real masters. I just want to use this library in my project.

Answer (score 0):

after asking and researching every nook and cranny TheLiTTle my good frend in xda-developer (BILLyTheLiTTle nick name in github ) give me a showcase that works like a charm now without any problem .. thanks to "amlcurran "for awesome free source saved me .

if someone want implement showcase on android studio and can't import it to gradle build system here i found fully working showcaseview  , i was so confused and sad before i found this and now i really feels happy , hope it help you my friend reading my post .

you can download it here and open it with studio Gradle build system .

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Answer (score 0):

also again great thank to billytheLittle , there is more detail of showcaseview working . his work and all code is available to you guy need to see codes in detail , you can fork it if you like for sure :

https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/Sepals/commit/056dc80dc0bcc3e235a46fd7dd6253487d676a04